# How are SSH commands sent so fast?

Tags: networking, ssh, tcp, network-programming

I wrote a Pythonn server/client socket/network program where the server runs in a cloud virtual machine and the client runs locally on my computer.

The client opens a TCP connection with the server, the server `accept()`s the connection, and afterwards it calls `recv()` a `while(1)` loop to listen to commands. When it receives a command (eg. `ls`) it runs it and sends back the output to the client.

Connecting to the virtual machine, running a command, and then exiting is 3x faster than `ssh` (0.7 secs vs 2.5 secs), but running single commands is much slower.

Eg. with `ssh`, after connecting, I run a command and the output seems (nearly?) instant, but on my program there's a noticeable delay.

How are SSH commands sent and returned so fast?

Comment: There is nothing inherently in SSH which makes code execution fast, so it might be more a problem of what your program is doing to make it slower. Unfortunately it is unclear what exactly you are doing and what causes the noticeable delay in your code, since no code is given.

Comment: It's nothing fancy, essentially just `send(sock)` (client), `recv(sock)` (server), `send(sock)` (server), `recv(sock)` (client).

Comment: But since you asked for code: https://pastecode.io/s/7bg5wkaq

Comment: The code is far from minimal, which makes it hard to focus on the problem. But what is obvious is that SSH provides you a shell session once you connect and execute each command within this shell. While your code executes a new shell for each new command (which might take a while with all the initialization) and then executes the command within this newly spawned shell. This means significantly more execution overhead per command.